# decorator design pattern violating is-a relationship

Tags: java, decorator

I have recently started studying about decorator design pattern but I have a query. Decorators implement the same interface as the Component they are trying to decorate. Doesn't this violate the is-a relationship. 
Moreover since the decorator has the component (through composition) , why is it really required for the decorator to implement the same component interface which the concrete component implements.?

Going through the decorator design pattern on Headfirst, it gives me a feeling that decorators can directly implement the component. There is no need to have an abstract class / interface for decorator.

I am worries that this could really be a dumb question but help would allow me to have a strong foundation.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain please?

Comment: Belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Basilevs: Can you please cite why this is off-topic for StackOverflow? Quoting from the Help section, on-topic questions include *practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development*.  That is certainly true of this question.  Sending interesting questions to a community with a tiny fraction of the participation of SO is not healthy for this community.

Comment: @Mark Peters I don't see any practical value in questions of this type. Moreover, it is impossible to provide a correct answer for questions of this type.

Comment: This problem is more theoretical than practical

Comment: It's completely pratical.  As a software engineer, I have to apply patterns like Decorator every single day.  I like having an appreciation for why it is valued over the alternatives.

Comment: @Alex: Why is it impossible to provide right answer here ?

Comment: If you read the GoF book they have lots of examples for each pattern

Comment: @Alex: Of course there are well-supported, well-researched answers for questions of this type.  The amount of literature on this topic is astounding.  Just because the answer can't be boiled down to a one-line "this is the semi-colon you need to add" doesn't mean it's subjective.

Comment: There's no 'theory' in patterns it's just a bunch of practical recommendations so it's impractical to discuss them from any philosophical standpoint. Surely, when we see them first we are astonished at their versatility hence come questions of this type. But it is practice only that can resolve them and thus it can not be 'explained'

Comment: @Alex: What on earth are you talking about?  Of course patterns can be explained.  And questions about them can be answered.  And those questions can involve theory, and the patterns embody design principles.

Comment: @MarkPeters No, patterns can not be explained, only shown. The act of showing does not presume any 'correctness'. It is possible to implement a decorator somehow wrongly and still have a perfect software program in terms of requirements

Comment: @Alex: *A singleton is a design pattern wherein a program enforces that only one instance of a class is created.* Are you saying that I didn't just explain Singleton, or that Singleton isn't a design pattern?

Comment: This is why I've fallen out of love with SO. It's full of pedants, backed up by some vague rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand the difference between composition and Decorator.  Decorator is a form of composition, but the main thing that sets it apart is that it does so in a way that lets the wrapper be used by code that would normally use the decorated object.

Let's use a common example to help explore the question.  Consider the interface `InputStream`.  I might have a method that copies bytes from one stream to another:

```
public static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) { ... }
```

Now say that we had a file that we wanted to copy.  I would create a `FileInputStream` and pass it to `copy()`.

But say I get a requirement that I need to count the number of bytes that were copied.

Well, I could create `CountingFileInputStream` which extends `FileInputStream`.  The `CountingFileInputStream` is-a `FileInputStream`.  But what if tomorrow I need to do the same thing for a `SocketInputStream`?  I'd have to create a `CountingSocketInputStream` that extends `SocketInputStream`.

I could instead use composition!  I could create a class that takes an `InputStream` and counts bytes that read to it:

```
public class StreamCounter {

   private final InputStream in;
   private long bytesRead;

   public int read() {
     int nextByte = in.read();
     if (nextByte != -1) bytesRead++;
     return nextByte;
   }
}
```

This can handle *any* `InputStream`, which is great.  But we can't use our existing code that takes an `InputStream`, because `StreamCounter` **is-not-an** `InputStream`.

So this is where Decorator comes in.  We can instead make a [`CountingInputStream`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CountingInputStream.html) that both implements `InputStream` (and so **is-an** `InputStream`) and delegates to another `InputStream`.  That way we can use it in our `copy()` method.

So in short, in terms of the `is-a` relationship, `CountingInputStream` is-an `InputStream` (which is usually all we care about) but it is-not-a `FileInputStream`, which allows it to wrap any `InputStream`, like a [`LimitInputStream`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#limit%28java.io.InputStream,%20long%29) which is decorating a [`DeflaterInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterInputStream.html) which is decorating a [`BufferedInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) which is decorating a [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html).  And at the end of the day, `copy()` doesn't need to care!

Comment: BufferedInputStream & LineNumberInput Stream are extending FilterInputStream. Hence, FilterInputStream acts as the abstract decorator class. Now FilterInputStream extends InputStream (component for Decorator pattern). What is the need for this FilterInputStream. Even if BufferedInputStream directly extends BufferedInputStream, the same objective would be achieved right? Hence to summarize I am unable to understand the significance of asbtract decorator class. Unlike above example from java.io, a lot of times the abstract decorator does not establish the is-a relationship with the component.

Comment: Could not thank you for your time to make me understand this in the last comment due to lack of space. Appreciate your help

Comment: @TarunBhatt: `FilterInputStream` is just a convenience class that makes it easier to implement a Decorator of `InputStream`s.  It's not essential to implement the pattern.  It basically just delegates all of its methods to a wrapped `InputStream`.  This is useful because a number of these Decorators don't need to change the behavior of *every* method.  For example, `CountingInputStream` doesn't need to change `flush()` or `close()`, so it's convenient that `FilterInputStream` does that already.

Comment: Oks so i think i m getting better clarity now. This means decorator classes like FilterInputStream would be consisting of methods which needs to be decorated and not all the methods from InputStream (component).

Answer (score 0):

It is your choice how you want to implement Decorator class based on use case. It is not mandatory for Decorator class to implement same interface.

So if you see `Collections.synchronizedCollection.(Collection<T> c)` , we have a static method here which is acting as decorator and same interface is not implemented.

But in implementationshown t this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/decorator_pattern.htm) Decorator class does implement the interface as use case needs it [as polymorphism is used].

So its not mandatory and there is no voilation of "is a" relationship.